# Configuring NFS mount to use LDAP user id

Tags: mount, authentication, nfs, 16.04, ldap

My research group uses LDAP authentication for all the desktops. However, we've purchased a few laptops and would like to set them up so that they don't require LDAP authentication (so we can work remotely without network access). However, there are some NFS shares that I need to access. I have successfully mounted them; however, I cannot figure out how to mount using the LDAP credentials (so that I can have the same permissions as if I was mounting from one of the LDAP-based computers).

I know what the LDAP UID and GID for my account are. Is there any way to tell the NFS mount to provide that UID/GID when mounting?

EDIT: Forgot to update the title. I've been working on this problem and originally attacked it from the wrong angle. I re-wrote the description but should have updated the title as well.

EDIT2: Fix typo.